# Why is "admission" countable in "Museum admission is $5."?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, articles, countability

[cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/admission):

> one of the meanings of "admission":
> *Admission is also the price paid to enter a place*.

> an example for this meaning:
> **(1)** *Museum admission is $5*.

Dictionary says "admission" in (1) is countable.

Why is "admission" in (1) countable?
If "admission" is countable, why is there not "a" or "the" before "museum admission"?

---

my variant with "a":
**(2)** ***A** museum admission is $5*.

Is (2) correct?
If it is, then what is the difference between (1) and (2)?
If not, then why not?

Comment: Words acquire meanings in particular domains.  The head of marketing  for the museum could say "Admission*s* **were** down last month", meaning "ticket sales" or "sales of tickets", referring to the number of visitors.  Analogous to "hospital admissions", where "admission" is the accepting of a patient into the hospital, and it is a countable datum.

Answer (score 1):

'[Admission](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/admission)', as in "*the price paid to enter a place*", is uncountable:

> [uncountable] the amount of money that you pay to go into a building or to an event

Note that it is *not necessarily* used in that way: it can also mean 'right to enter' (e.g. "*how much for an admission?*"), and in your case this right will cost a person $5.
Interpreting it this way, your variant "*A museum admission is $5*" is indeed correct.

Answer (score -1):

One could understand *an admission* here to mean the admitting of one person. But it’s not idiomatic.